# Is this a 'proper' way to represent a circuit schematic?

Tags: best-practice, drawing

Is this a reasonable way to do a wiring diagramme. What are the common practices when making this sort of thing?[image]

Basically I am a compleat beginner and would love to know if this is a proper neat way to represent a circuit schematic.

Comment: What do you mean by "wiring"? Is it a PCB or a cable interconnected components?

Comment: It's okay.  You could make the diagram less cluttered if you made use of Ground and Vdd symbols - the majority of the wires would then represent signals rather than power supply nets.  Personal preference, I guess.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am using Vero board it is just a representation of connections

Comment: So it is a circuit schematic.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, yes

Comment: Just to be sure, you aren't asking for us to point out any obvious errors in your schematic, right?  Only the drawing style?

Comment: The #1 improvement would be to use power and ground symbols instead of routing them all around.

Comment: @Justin yes, but If you see an obvious error then I would appreciate it.

Comment: This question is yet answered [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28255/104387).

Comment: You could use some net names & to avoid crossing of nets, which makes it look less cluttered, you can break the nets by providing same net names & leave them hanging so the same net name will connect them.